# Can I make a MySQL trigger execute before the actual triggering statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a trigger on a child table that updates a counter on a parent table.  Regardless of whether I `CREATE TRIGGER ... BEFORE INSERT` or `AFTER INSERT` the SQL in the trigger is always executed after.

Is there a way to force it run before?

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  quantity_sold int(11) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE line_items (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  item_id int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  quantity int(11) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO items (id) VALUES (1);

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS line_item_trigger;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER line_item_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON line_items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE items SET quantity_sold = quantity_sold + NEW.quantity WHERE id = NEW.item_id;
END
$$
```

Running:

```sql
INSERT INTO line_items (item_id) VALUES (1);
```

...results in:

```sql
INSERT INTO line_items (item_id) VALUES (1);
UPDATE items SET quantity_sold = quantity_sold + NEW.quantity WHERE id = NEW.item_id;
```

I'm hoping to have the `UPDATE` happen first.

(Why? This is all done in a transaction and the `INSERT` is locking the `items` table when it does the foreign key check, causing deadlocks all over the place.)

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: are you executing multiple inserts into `line_items` in one transaction?

Comment: As fas as I know the trigger will first update your query before he insert a new row. This is how triggers works from my experience

Comment: @ilya bursov  It's just a single line item insert in each transaction.

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you are trying to do. The trigger will be triggered by the `insert` on the logic level. How MySQL internally executes it (e.g. when it locks, when it changes the actual tables, ...) is not really under your control (although you have some influence on it). To enforce a different (logical) order, execute these statements separately (without a trigger), maybe in a procedure - although I'm not sure it can solve your deadlock. So maybe take a step and describe your deadlock, a.k.a. your actual problem, not ask how to implement the solution you thought of to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER line_item_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON line_items
FOR EACH ROW
```

This trigger is enforced to invoke ahead of insertion. There is nothing more need to do for that.

Please check your **commit** frequency as per need to make sure you are committing the transaction.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I'm wanting the UPDATE from the trigger to run before the INSERT instead of after. The sequence currently is BEGIN / INSERT / UPDATE / COMMIT so commits are happening quite frequently.

Comment: As per your trigger mentioned in your question, order will  be BEGIN / UPDATE / INSERT. I could not see an `commit` on shared code, so I cant comment where will it happen. If you have commit in place check  what is causing the deadlock by finding the deadlocked queries from DB.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example where this behavior is demonstrated?.

The following example updates the `row_count_line_items` column of `items` table from `BEFORE TRIGGER`, counting the number of rows in `line_items` table. As it's a `BEFORE TRIGGER`, `row_count_line_items` column is zero (0) (`INSERT` was not done at that moment):

```sql
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `line_item_trigger`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `line_items`, `items`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `quantity_sold` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
    ->   `row_count_line_items` int,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `line_items` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `item_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `quantity` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES items (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `items` (`id`) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `line_item_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `line_items`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    ->   UPDATE `items`
    ->   SET `quantity_sold` = `quantity_sold` + NEW.`quantity`,
    ->       `row_count_line_items` = (SELECT COUNT(`id`)
    ->                                 FROM `line_items`)
    ->   WHERE `id` = NEW.`item_id`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `line_items` (`item_id`) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> COMMIT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `quantity_sold`, `row_count_line_items`
    -> FROM `items`;
+----+---------------+----------------------+
| id | quantity_sold | row_count_line_items |
+----+---------------+----------------------+
|  1 |             1 |                    0 |
+----+---------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `item_id`, `quantity`
    -> FROM `line_items`;
+----+---------+----------+
| id | item_id | quantity |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |
+----+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qJcuUUpuA457vnR7VoLtuS/2).

If we change the event to `AFTER` (`AFTER TRIGGER`), then `row_count_line_items` column will have the value of one (1) (because, `INSERT` was already done):

```
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `line_item_trigger`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `line_items`, `items`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `quantity_sold` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
    ->   `row_count_line_items` int,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `line_items` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `item_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `quantity` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES items (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `items` (`id`) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `line_item_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `line_items`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    ->   UPDATE `items`
    ->   SET `quantity_sold` = `quantity_sold` + NEW.`quantity`,
    ->       `row_count_line_items` = (SELECT COUNT(`id`)
    ->                                 FROM `line_items`)
    ->   WHERE `id` = NEW.`item_id`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `line_items` (`item_id`) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `quantity_sold`, `row_count_line_items`
    -> FROM `items`;
+----+---------------+----------------------+
| id | quantity_sold | row_count_line_items |
+----+---------------+----------------------+
|  1 |             1 |                    1 |
+----+---------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> COMMIT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `item_id`, `quantity`
    -> FROM `line_items`;
+----+---------+----------+
| id | item_id | quantity |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |
+----+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qJcuUUpuA457vnR7VoLtuS/3).